# Как при чекеде чекбокса конце урл добавить параметры?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть 5 checkbox:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каждый раз при выборе checkbox надо ставить в конце ссылки

```
<a href="/index.php?route=extension/module/brainyfilter/filter&bfilter=f1:2,3;">Применить</a>
```

то что находится в `value` чекбокса (пример 1,2,4).
Все реализую, получаю `value`, НО именно добавить в конец ссылки не получается. Как это сделать ?

Comment: Вам нужно менять значение bfilter в ссылке ?

Comment: да именно так, вот эти параметры http://prntscr.com/h6ocfx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно вот так например:

> Код HTML

```
<a class="element_a" href="/index.php?route=extension/module/brainyfilter/filter&bfilter=f1:">Применить</a>

<div class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="1">1 Седан</label> 
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="2">2 Купе</label> 
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="3">3 Хэтчбек</label>
</div>
```

> Код jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(".checkbox [type='checkbox']").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) { 
        $('.element_a').attr("href", $('.element_a').attr('href')+$(this).val()+"," )  
    }else{
        var str = $('.element_a').attr("href");
        var a_href = str.replace($(this).val()+",", "" );  
        $('.element_a').attr("href", a_href ); 
    }
});

</script>
```

> Результат примера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да класс! Сильно изменится код если вместе чекбокса было тег a ?

Comment: Да, нужно будет переписать некоторые моменты. Например $(this).val() с тегом <a></a> не сработает. Нажо будет изменить $(".checkbox [type='checkbox']") на $("a"), так же поменять .change(function() на .click(function(), переделать конструкцию if(this.checked)

Comment: В принципе не сложно поменять если есть хоть какие то понимания JS/Jquey

Comment: Хорошо попробую